# Strange Boost::Lexical_cast conversion

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

To make it short, here is the code :

```
std::string m_specs = "f500000";
float m_sten = 21.0;
std::cout << m_specs << std::endl;
m_specs = "f" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_sten);
std::cout << m_specs << std::endl;
```

The first output will be :

> f500000

, but the second will be

> f6.70932579e+028

The expect result is

> f21.0

I don't have any idea why is this conversion so strange... I need your lights.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the first line, you use `m_sten` but in the 3rd line, you use `m_stren`. Also, why are you lexical casting a string to a string? What are you trying to do? Are you sure you're doing it right?

Comment: Edited, sorry, this isn't it.

Comment: [ideone](http://ideone.com/etRdIb) disagrees with you.  How about a complete example?

Comment: Voting to close as we've now gotten two defective code snippets which fail to repro the issue. OP, please get the issue to actually occur in code you can post without alteration. (Use ideone!)

Answer (score 2):

Your code switches between `m_stren` and `m_sten`.

Are you sure you're not mixing up two different but similarly named variables?

Comment: Oh, sorry, when I post something, I always make the code shorter and forgot some little things, I'll edit the code fast, this isn't a varame problem, I just make mistake in the code on SOF. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I found out the solution, in fact, m_sten wasn't really declared. I forgot to declared it by a function. Thank for having attention on this.